# Functor that does not preserve monic and epic

Tags: category-theory, examples-counterexamples, functors

In Jacobson’s book BAII, he gave two exercises to show that there exists functor that does not preserve monic or epic.

> Ex-1.Let M and N be monoids as categories with a single object. Show that in this identification,a functor is a homomorphism of M into N.

> Ex-2.Use Ex-1 to construct a functor $F$ and a monic(epic) $f$ such that $F(f)$ is not monic(epic)

I have solved Ex-1. However, I don’t know how to construct concrete example to solve Ex-2.

I do hope someone can give me some hints. Thank you very much!

Comment: You need to understand what it means for an element $m\in M$ to be monic or epic when $M$ is viewed as a category. Then it shouldn't be hard to invent a homomorphism which doesn't respect these properties.

Comment: @KevinArlin I think that $m\in M$ should satsify $ma=mb\Rightarrow a=b$ so that $m$ is a monic. And my counfusion is that I can’t construct the concrete example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $M$ be a free monoid.

> A simple example is with $M=(\Bbb N,+),\ \,N=(\{0,1\},\max)$ and $F(m)=\min(1,m)$.
>  $1$ is cancellable in $M$ but not in $N$.